# why the output of subprocess.Popen is not the same as expected?

Tags: python, django, subprocess

I have a Django server which trying to run with subprocess.Popen and store all the logs on a file, this is my code:

```py
    with open('thefile.log', 'a') as the_file:
        p1 = subprocess.Popen(['python', os.getcwd() + '\\mySite\\manage.py', 'runserver'], stdout=the_file,
                             stderr=the_file, universal_newlines=True)
```

and this is the result in the thefile.log:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
[26/Jul/2019 13:10:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16348
[26/Jul/2019 13:10:05] "GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1" 200 423
[26/Jul/2019 13:10:06] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85692
[26/Jul/2019 13:10:06] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 86184
[26/Jul/2019 13:10:06] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85876
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[26/Jul/2019 13:10:08] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1976
Not Found: /fs
[26/Jul/2019 13:10:11] "GET /fs HTTP/1.1" 404 1949
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 26, 2019 - 13:09:44
Django version 2.2.3, using settings 'mySite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

but it should be like this:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader

Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 26, 2019 - 13:09:44
Django version 2.2.3, using settings 'mySite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

[26/Jul/2019 13:10:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16348
[26/Jul/2019 13:10:05] "GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1" 200 423
[26/Jul/2019 13:10:06] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85692
[26/Jul/2019 13:10:06] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 86184
[26/Jul/2019 13:10:06] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85876
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[26/Jul/2019 13:10:08] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1976
Not Found: /fs
[26/Jul/2019 13:10:11] "GET /fs HTTP/1.1" 404 1949
```

in fact I have some other serivices, my other question is that How can I print the result of them in propper way with subprocess.Popen on my current terminal? for example:

```
service1:
      ------
      ------
service2:
      ------
      ------
```

Answer (score 3):

You can not route `stdout` and `stderr` to the same file handler like that. You can however use a trick here to "route" the `stderr` to the `stdout` (or vice-versa), like:

```
with open('thefile.log', 'a') as the_file:
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(
        ['python', os.getcwd() + '\\mySite\\manage.py', 'runserver'],
        stdout=the_file,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        universal_newlines=True
    )
```

This looks similar to a shell where you write `python manage.py runserver >> thefile.log 2>&1`.

Comment: Thanks for your point, but doing that doesn`t have any reflection on correcting the order of logs on the log files. Do you have any idea about my second question, Is there any way to show the result of subprocess.Popen on the current terminal?

Comment: @LordST: the new logs will be placed after the previous ones of course (since you append). What do you mean with the result? The status code?

Comment: @LordST: you can use `tee` to obtain a "copy" of the stream, and thus print this to the `stdout`. You probably want to use something like `ncurses` if you want to update two parts of your screen with `logs`: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html